# bootstrap navbar-right not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and I was trying something and found a problem

I have a 2 different navbar-header class, which I want to put it both in left and right hand side and I want it to be responsive

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav " style="opacity:0.8" role="navigation">
    <div class="container " >
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class=" topnav" href="#">image1</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="navbar-right" >
            <a class=" topnav" href="#">image2</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

when I view it in mobile, view right-hand part comes to bottom but I wanted it to stay at top both in mobile and desktop view

http://plnkr.co/edit/g1CwhhyDrSoVf3zTRl6E?p=preview

Any help is highly appreciated
THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping them in a row then in col-xs-* classes

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav "     style="opacity:0.8" role="navigation">
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class=" topnav" href="#">image1</a>
          </div>              
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="navbar-right" >
              <a class=" topnav" href="#">image2</a>
          </div>              
        </div>

      </div><!--./row-->
    </div><!--./container-->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav " style="opacity:0.8" role="navigation">
    <div class="container " >

      <div class=row>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class=" topnav" href="#">image1</a>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="navbar-right" >
            <a class=" topnav" href="#">image2</a>
        </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

It is not the best option but, try this =)